# Log4j2 WebLookup

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 (2.0.2) in a servlet 3.0 web application, running in Tomcat 8.0.12. I'm trying to use the weblookup to get the web app context path to use as part of the log file name. (We run the same war file under several different contexts using properties to configure it).

The log4j2.xml file includes

```
        <RollingFile name="Web" fileName="/srv/dnsnet/logs/web-${web:contextPath}.logfile" filePattern="/srv/dnsnet/logs/web-${web:contextPath}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" append="true" immediateFlush="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %-5p [%25.25t] %40.40c{3.} %15X{sysid} %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="8"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

But the web:contextPath does not get resolved. I have got log4j-web-2.0.2.jar in my web app. I added some messages to the WebLookup class, and the problem is that the external context of the LoggerContext is null.

So I tried to see where the LoggerContext is created. The stack trace when the LoggerContext constructor is called is

```
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl$PrivateManager.getContext(LogFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getLoggersMap(LogFactoryImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractMyFacesListener.<clinit>(AbstractMyFacesListener.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:647)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5164)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

But the ClassLoaderContextSelector always passes null for the external context. So it looks as though I'm missing something.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, or missing?  Do I have to specify a different ContextSelector?

Answer (score 1):

You may have found a bug in log4j. I suspect it is the combination of Commons Logging and the WebLookup that does not work. Can you verify if this is the case (check if the WebLookup works if your application  uses the log4j 2 API instead of Commons Logging) and file a bug report in the log4j2 Jira [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2)?

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the real application as it is large and has all sorts of dependencies I can't control. But I will try to create a simple test app to investigate your suggestion.

Comment: My simple app isn't working either. The only jars in the webapp are log4j-core, log4j-api and log4j-web.

Comment: I've also found that under Tomcat 7.0.55 my main app does resolve the weblookup initially, but when only until it logs org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer "ServletContext 'xyz' initialized". After that the weblookup fails. But under Tomcat 8.0.12 it never works. Still digging...

Comment: In my simple app, I discovered that weblookup only works if there is a <display-name> element in the web.xml. That doesn't sound right, as display-name is optional as far as I can see from the XSD.

Comment: Wow! Definitely file a bug report for this then.

Comment: Hello @RemkoPopma, has the enforced <display-name> bug been resolved in Tomcat 7.0.59? We use log4j2 in our deployments and we need to be able to do ${web:xxx} lookups within but we can't get this part to work. Our configurations are all Spring configuration java based beans instead of xml based and I don't know where we can set the display-name value to see if that is the problem why web lookups are not working for us...